# Is there a media query for the viewport size of a zoomed area? ( iPhone )

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css

Say you have a 1200px x 1000px webpage that you are developing.  When one of your test users pinches in on the webpage, say 50% of the original size, the viewport would be 600px x 500px.

Are there any media queries that will fire once the user zooms 50%, 600px x 500px in this case?

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to achieve? If zooming is allowed, then user can zoom to 50% of the original size. Do you want to restrict zooming somehow?

Comment: No, I want to a media query to fire when the webpage is zoomed to a specific level.  In this case 600px X 500px.

Comment: I believe zooming like this on an iPhone is done GPU side, and thus has no effect on the actual amount of pixels the website is showing.

Comment: According to the iOs documentation ([here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006509-SW32)), the width of the viewport is set on first time and safari applies a scaling factor on zooming (see the examples) which does not change the viewport's size.

Answer (score 0):

These two articles cover the viewport topics better than anything else I've seen:

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html

http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html